# PG::Error - Refinery CMS - Blog Post Create Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, refinerycms, rails-postgresql, refinery

I'm getting an error whenever I try to create a new blog post.
I am running refinery 2.1 with the blog gem installed. I have recently upgraded from 2.0 and have migrated and seeded the database. I am getting a PG Constraint error in my log.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "refinery_blog_post_id" violates not-null constraint
```

It is hosted on heroku. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue here.